How to integrate a matrixexponential multiplicated with a sin function?
i am looking for the analytic solution of the following integration:
$\int_{0}^{t}e^{-A\cdot \tau}\cdot D\cdot sin(\omega \cdot t) d\tau $,
with $\omega \in \mathbb R$, $t>0$, diagonalizable matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$,matrix $D\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ and $e^{-A\cdot \tau}$ as matrixexponential.
In my opinion the problem can be reformulated into:
$\int_{0}^{t}V\cdot e^{-A_D\cdot \tau}\cdot V^{-1} \cdot D\cdot sin(\omega \cdot t) d\tau $, where
$V$ denote the eigenvectormatrix and $A_D$ the diagonalmatrix with respect to $A$. I am not shure if i can continue like the following:
$V\cdot\int_{0}^{t} e^{-A_D\cdot \tau}\cdot sin(\omega \cdot t) d\tau \cdot V^{-1} \cdot D$ ?
